# Real part of Arcsine of a Complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we show: $\operatorname{Re}({\arcsin{z}}) = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2x+1} -\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2x+1})$ ?
None of the things I tried including using the formula of inverse sine seems to work... Please Help

Comment: A problem in Spiegel,M.R., Complex Variables, McGraw-Hill ?

Comment: Yes indeed ,This is my Main Book for independent study of this subject.........

Comment: A misprint. It should be $$\operatorname{Re}(\arcsin z)=\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2x+1} -\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2x+1})\right).$$

Comment: Any clue as to how a solution should be obtained??

Comment: Let $\arcsin (x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then $x+iy=\sin(u+iv)=\sin u\cosh v+i\cos u\sinh v,$ that is, $x=\sin u\cosh v, y=\cos u\sinh v$. Eliminate $u$. You will get $\cosh^4 v-(x^2+y^2+1)\cosh^2 v +x^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will go over this tonight and see if I can understand it

Comment: Hi ,I still do not see how this helps if we solve for coshv we just get a very complicated expression involving x and y......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the equation $(\cosh^2 v)^2-(x^2+y^2+1)\cosh^2 v +x^2=0\,\,$  we have
$$
\cosh ^2v=\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2+1+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+1)^2-4x^2}\right)$$
since $\cosh^2 v=1+\sinh^2 v\ge 1$.
Noting $$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right)\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2+1+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+1)^2-4x^2}\right),$$
we have$$
\cosh v=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right).$$
Therefore $$\sin u=\frac{x}{\cosh v}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right),
$$which ensures $$u=\operatorname{Re}(\arcsin (x+iy))=\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right)\right).$$